# Laravel cookie not available on home page

Tags: laravel, session, cookies, csrf

I want to use session on Laravel home page for a form.. But session is not working only on home page. Please help.

I have set session lifetime as 120 and domain as example.com.

The session is available in all other pages.

I think cookie is being set for session but is not available on same request of home page.

I know you might have oxford degree in english and i do not have it..Little time of your highness would be appreciated..

Comment: Instead of throwing your anger by giving negative points..your take on this in form of comments would be appreciated..i am facing this issue since 3 days..

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? And does your home page route have the `web` middleware group applied?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attention, I have latest version and it has web.php in the routes folder which automatically includes all routes in web middleware.

Comment: I dont understand the same form works in second/third/fourth page but not in the first page of my website..What i observe is cookie is present in all other pages except first..But when i come back from other pages to first pages, the cookie is there and my form works which is dependent on session..but this does not happen on the first time i land on my website..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 
I created a table in database mimicking the job of cookie. Its working now..